# select2 selected options not getting selected tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-select2

I just started using select2 for my dynamic ajax dropdowns. But I just cant get it working correctly.
All my options are loaded remotely via ajax and selecting an option works too.

But I cant read the :selected option, because the currently selected options doesnt get the ":selected"-tag. I am using the newest release Select2 4.0.13

This is what my DOM looks like after selecting an option:

```html
<select id="city" class="form-control city select2-hidden-accessible valid" name="city" style="width: 100%;" data-select2-id="city" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-invalid="false">
    <option value="79" data-select2-id="414">Aldenhoven</option>
    <option value="53" data-select2-id="1211">Alpen</option>
    <option value="168" data-select2-id="1610">Ahaus</option>
</select>
```

Whenever I select a new option, it gets appended. If I select a previous options, then nothing changes.

This is how I initialised the select2:

```html
$('#city').empty();
$('#city').select2({
  dropdownParent: $('#city').parent(),
  placeholder: 'Bitte wählen Sie die Ort..',
  ajax: {
    url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>xxxxxxx/GetAllCities',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
      var query = {
        search: params.term,
        type: 'public'
      }
      return query;
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
      return {
        results: data
      };
    },
    cache: true
  }
});
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: I forgot to mention when I do "$('#city').children("option:selected").val()" I get "undefined"